# Html.BeginForm in partial for a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, html.beginform

I have the following code:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Comments", FormMethod.Post)) { %>
<div id="New_Comment">
<textarea name="newComment" id="newComment">Add comments</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Add" />
<div><span class="text_grey">Attach:</span><a href="#" class="link_text_grey">File</a> <a href="#" class="link_text_grey">Link</a></div>
</div>
<%} %>
```

This is in a partial rendered by the MyPage controller. For some reason the action on the form comes out blank, if I reference a method on the MyPage controller it works fine what I want to do is point to a different controller with my form.

Comment: Looks right to me. Is there somewhere we can look at the generated HTML? The action should be `/Comments/AddComment` relative to the site root.

Comment: The generated html just has no action <form action="" method="post">

Comment: Try to be more exhaustive. I just tried to recreate your problem but I had the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue I simple added in an area route value like so:

```
new { area = "" }
```

With the empty string directing the route to the default area.

Comment: Did not know that was even possible. So many magic strings... but hey it worked.

Answer (score 2):

1) Is your "Comments" action marked as being a POST action?

2) Also

Try just doing:

```
<% Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Comments"); %>

// Html and script

<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

I know that there shouldn't be difference between what you have and what I suggest, but it's worth a try.